# How to run three activities one splash screen,one by pressing button and one last activity?

Tags: android

I am developing an app having three activities:One Launcher activity(Splash Screen activity),second activity starting next to splash screen and one activity launches by pressing the button on second activity.So please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Refer this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: startActivity=new Intent(yourActivity.this,NextActivity.class);

Comment: Did you even go through the android docs or any website before posting a question even ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `Intents`
For example 
In your `SplashActivity`

```
in = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,NextActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

`OnClick` of `Button` of next activity

```
btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    in = new Intent(NextActivity.this,Next2Activity.class);
    startActivity(in);

});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using intent

```
 Intent secondIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(secondIntent);
    finish();




    OnClick of Button of Second activity

    secondActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent lastActivityIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,LastActivity.class);
        startActivity(lastActivityIntent );
});
}
```